# create a new list, L3, that sums the two numbers if the number from L1 is greater than 10 and the number from L2 is less than 5

Tags: python, zip, list-comprehension

I am working on this problem and cannot seem to get it.

Here is L1 and L2 which was provided:

```py
L1 = [1, 5, 2, 16, 32, 3, 54, 8, 100]
L2 = [1, 3, 10, 2, 42, 2, 3, 4, 3]
```

Beow is the solution that I came up with (L3) but it is not skipping the numbers > 10 and numbers < 5, Please help and explain!

```py
L3 = [x1 + x2 for (x1, x2) in zip(L1, L2) if x1 > 10 or x2 < 5]
```

Here is the output:

Actual: `[2, 8, 18, 74, 5, 57, 12, 103]`
Expected: `[18, 57, 103]`

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code step by step? What about transforming the list comprehension into a regular for loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong in your code is that you should have used `and` for the condition instead of an `or`:

```py
L3 = [x1 + x2 for (x1, x2) in zip(L1, L2) if x1 > 10 and x2 < 5]
```

```
>>> L3
[18, 57, 103]
```

Comment: Thanks A-lot! I thought i did that but it did not work for me. It sure does now!

Comment: @WorldTechSolutions If my answer solves your question, could you click the accept button at the left of my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
L3 = [(x+y) for (x,y) in zip(L1,L2) if x > 10 and y < 5 ]